# How to automate an update for a column in SQL

Tags: automation, updates

I am very much new at SQL. Hopefully someone will be able to help with this problem. I need to create an query that will automate the updates of one of my column. How do I go about writing that?Any help would be much appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

Please do following actions, (JAVA)

1. Add DB driver dependency to your program
2. Construct your query
3. Pass it your DB driver

   ```
               try {
                   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+url+"/VSS-AlertManager?user="+username+"&password="+password);
                   st = con.createStatement();
                   rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                   while (rs.next()) {
                       ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                       int colCount = md.getColumnCount();
                       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                       for (int i = 1; i <= colCount ; i++){
                           String col_name = md.getColumnName(i);
                           String col_value = rs.getString(col_name);
                           System.out.println(col_name + col_value );
                       }

                   }
               } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException  throwables) {
                   throwables.printStackTrace();
                   log.error("Error occurred in executing mysql : "+throwables.toString());
               }
   ```